# How can I focus in the camera?

Tags: reactjs, camera, focus

I have an add image component where the user can add images and files and can take photos with the camera. Now I want the user to be able to focus on the camera .In fact, I want to have something similar to the ability to focus in phone cameras. And that the image in some phones is wide

```
<video ref={videoRef} autoPlay></video>

 useEffect(() => {
        const constraints = {
            audio: false,
            video: { facingMode: "environment" },
        };

        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then((stream) => {
                videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
                videoRef.current.play();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                return error
            });

        return () => {
            // Cleanup: stop the video stream when the component is unmounted
            const videoElement = videoRef.current;
            if (videoElement && videoElement.srcObject) {
                const stream = videoElement.srcObject;
                if (stream.getTracks) {
                    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
                } else if (stream.stop) {
                    stream.stop();
                }
            }
        };
    }, []);
```

Comment: In react or react-native !?

Comment: No Its web Application @BabakYaghoobi